# Connection to Eucalyptus is being refused

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus

I copied two Ubuntu VMs (cloud server and the node) from a computer to another. On the first computer it was working fine but on second one the browser Firefox is showing some "Internal Error(2)" when I type the address of the server machine. Please help me resolve it. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and VMware 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide enough details on what you did. If you moved the cloud-in-a-box version, and changed IP addresses of the services, then of course the whole cloud won't work. Part of the configuration is to *register* the components, which means, make them aware of each others IP address. Changing IP will require a new registration.